# How to catch BrokenRuleException in PLINQO?

Tags: exception, plinqo

I’ve created a custom rule by adding the

```
 static partial void AddSharedRules()
 {
            RuleManager.AddShared<Tag>(
                new CustomRule<String>(
                    "TagName",
                    "Invalid Tag Name, must be between 1 and 50 characters",
                    IsNullEmptyOrLarge));
 }
```

to my Entity class.

I then added the rule (as seen on the video, although the video is dated and has wrong information):

```
public static bool IsNullEmptyOrLarge( string value )
    {
        return (value == null
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
            || value.Length > 50);
    }
```

But now I have the calling code…

```
try    
{    
    // some code
}
catch ( CodeSmith.Data.Rules… ??? )
{

// I can’t add the BrokenRuleException object. It’s not on the list.
}
```

I have: assign, security and Validation.

What’s the correct way to catch broken rule exceptions in PLINQO?

Comment: Great, now I've got the Price is Right theme song stuck in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need to do, first add a reference in your project to

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

using CodeSmith.Data.Rules;
```

Then

```
try
{
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (BrokenRuleException ex)
{
    foreach (BrokenRule rule in ex.BrokenRules)
    {
        Response.Write("<br/>" + rule.Message);
    }
}
```

If you want to change the default message then you can go to your entity and change the attribute from

```
[Required]
```

to

```
[CodeSmith.Data.Audit.Audit]
private class Metadata
{
    // Only Attributes in the class will be preserved.

    public int NameId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="please please please add a firstname!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

You can also use these types of data annotation attributes

```
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage= "The name cannot exceed 10 characters long")]
    [Range(10, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Rippo, as usual, you’ve been very helpful, both here and @ the PLINQO forums.